# SQL SUM without rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I have the following query that gives a rounded result. How can I modify this to

- Stop rounding
- Display to 2 decimal places. E.g 3.456 -> 3.45

`SELECT SUM(Invoice_Details.Amount) AS TotalNet_C FROM Invoice_Details WHERE Invoice_Details.Invoice_Number = ||InvNo||`

Comment: SELECT
1.0 * SUM(Invoice_Details.Amount) AS TotalNet_C 

FROM
Invoice_Details

WHERE 
Invoice_Details.Invoice_Number = ||InvNo||

Comment: Do you mean you want to round down?  So after summing you get 3.456 you want it to be 3.45.  If you get 3.451 you want it to be 3.45.  The sum by itself should not be rounding.  If you had 2 values, say 1.7489390 and .0000001 you would get 1.7489391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format it to 2 digits you can e.g. convert it to currency.

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Invoice_Details.Amount) AS money) AS TotalNet_C 
FROM Invoice_Details
WHERE Invoice_Details.Invoice_Number = ||InvNo||
```

For be more specific you can use `CONVERT`.
Check this for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx

About rounding: You want to crop the digits, not round them:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(3.456 * 100 AS int) as float)/100
```

This will do it. Your case then

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(SUM(Invoice_Details.Amount) * 100 AS int) as float)/100 AS money) AS TotalNet_C 
FROM Invoice_Details
WHERE Invoice_Details.Invoice_Number = ||InvNo||
```

Comment: This looks like it would do but I get a syntax error when testing it.

Comment: I tested it with 'SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(SUM(3.456) * 100 AS int) as float)/100 AS money) AS TotalNet_C ' and it works fine, what error do you get?

Comment: oops, my fault. Was saying syntax error around SELECT... I'd pasted incorrectly so it started SELECT SELECT. Solution works perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this for rounding your value

```
  Str(ColumnName, 10, 2)

10-- this is for total length of your value.
2-- this is for how many decimal you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Num decimal(6,3)

set @Num = 3.456

 select LEFT(round(@Num, 2, 1),4)
OR 
select CAST(round(@Num, 2, 1)AS MONEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should to convert value before sum_function and u can use parameters of the numeric/decimal, just like this:

```
select SUM(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,2), value) from TestTable ...
```